# Append/Update params to an existing form using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, boolean, form-for

Fairly new to rails, meaning I believe I have most of the basics down, but definitely still a student of the art.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** append params to an existing form using form_for.

*So, I need to find the id for an existing form and pass a new hash to this form using the JobsController to append several columns of data.*

Steps are to select the job number from a select_box, add any changes/notes for that job using text_fields/check_boxes, then submit.  Also view used is a partial, found in views/jobs.

**Current problem**, despite several attempts, is: 
    **Overriding the default `'post'` method --tried several combinations of the following: `method => 'put'`, `:action => update, :controller => :jobs`**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :note, :twgid, :padd, :lnkbr, :txtwr, :datewr, :pinmiss, :headch,  :name, :nucopy, :minrend, :majrend, :lnkwr, :gmail, :hotmail, :aol, :outlook, :note, :linkwr

belongs_to :form
end


 JobsController: 

 ( scaffolded ) 


View: (jobs/_form.html.erb)

<%= form_for @job do |f| %>

   <fieldset> 
 <div class="form-horizontal">              
 <div class="control-group">
 <span class="control-label">
 <%= f.label :name, "TWGID" %></span>
 <%= f.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(Job.all, :name, :name), :prompt =>  'Select' %>  
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
 <div class="control-group">
 <span class="control-label">
  <%= f.label :padd, "Add Padding?" %></span>
  <%= f.check_box :padd %>   
  <%= f.hidden_field, :updated, :value => '1' %>
  <% end %>
```

##Routes##

```
get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

resources :sessions
resources :users 
resources :forms 
resources :projects
resources :jobs
root :to => 'forms#index'
```

Comment: One last comment: Strange thing is, my models are nested, so normally I would use f.fields_for :jobs, but this doesn't produce the params hash I think I need and I get from :fields_for :job, i.e. "job"=>{"updated"=>"1"}

Comment: if you use fields_for on an association you should actually get a hash that looks like this `"jobs_attributes"=>{[0]=>{"updated"=>"1"}}` Rails will know how to deal with that as long as you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` which i see you do

Comment: Yeah the issue is the way in which I'm using the 'update' action -- Normally `form_for @change` would select the appropriate http action automatically, however I'm trying to append attributes to an existing form using `'put'`, tried passing `:method => "put"` using various combinations of `form_for` and `fields_for` -- either way I either get the default 'post' action that creates a new record or an error -- so, at this point, I've migrated the 'changes' attributes to 'jobs' and created a jobs controller -- I'm trying to: _use form_for to find an existing record and append attributes_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do but let me take a crack at it.

Well, the first thing I see is that in update_job on the first line you try grabbing a Change object and putting it into @change. The problem is that your using @change.id which obviously hasn't been set yet. If you are getting the id through params you will want to use:

```
@change = Change.find(params[:id])
```

Second, you are trying to update an attribute of Job but have a Change object. This will not work.

What I think your trying to do overall is to build a form that updates a change and will also update its associations (jobs in this case). A quick link on how to do this is here:

[Form Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html%20Form%20Helpers) <--- Search for Nested Attributes Examples

Here is the code I would suggest:

```
<%= form_for @change do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :job do |j| %>
    Updated  : <%= j.check_box :updated %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will put the updated option in `params[:change][:jobs_attributes]` and when you send params[:change] into your update like so, `@change.update_attributes(params[:change])` it will update your job as well.

Comment: I can't edit your comment but could you please put that code in a code block please? I will edit my comment when it is :).... to continue I would need your routes file (post it as an edit on your main question) and maybe a bit more detailed version of your view. Also it wouldn't hurt to get a listing of the params that come through on your current submission

Comment: By code block i mean use the ticks to the left of number 1 like this `Some Code` (man there is going to be a lot of editing of comments on this one :P)

Comment: `def update_job @change=Change.find(params[:id]) @change.update_attributes(params[:change])`  I get _"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /changes Couldn't find Change without an ID."_  Also, I'm now attempting to pass the params using a hidden field,  i.e. `<%= fields_for :job do |ff| %> <%= ff.hidden_field, :updated, :value => '1' %>` Thanks for the help!

Comment: Significantly revised the post to simplify the problem and clarify -- still would like to know how to accomplish this task using the prior set-up -- my hunch is the solution can be used in either case.  Thanks again Bill!